# UINavigationItem: Fill container horizontally with TitleView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder

I am trying to design the navigation bar of a navigation controller in xcode interface builder. However, I can't correctly position the title view of the navigationitem. I tried titleview -> size inspector -> Arrange -> Fill container horizontally (since there's no way to set autolayout constraints for the title view). While this works for some screen sizes, doesn't work for others. How could I position the title view, so that, it fills the navigation item's entire width in every device size?

[image]

Comment: The size of the title view is not up to you. Instead of a single view, use a left bar button item, a title, and a right bar button item. Even better, this does not look at all like a navigation bar's normal contents, so maybe it would be better not to have a navigation bar at all; that way, you could design this however you like in a normal view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are designing is evidently not typical of a navigation bar. So it would be simplest to dispense with the navigation bar entirely and just design your view as a normal view at the top of the interface.

Alternatively, why not use a left bar button item and a right bar button item? I had little difficulty in emulating your interface (as a proof of concept, no more) in that way:

[image]

Comment: Thanks matt. My requirement is for the navigationBar to hide on scroll (when scrolling the associated table). IOS itself provides this animation and I was unsuccessful imitating the behavior with a normal view. Do you think I can get the same effect with a regular view?

Comment: I've never done it, but I don't see why you couldn't imitate it pretty well. You know what the scroll view is doing by acting as delegate, and animating a view off the screen is standard stuff. — Note that I am not saying "You shouldn't use a navigation bar." I'm just saying that if you _are_ going to use a navigation bar you need to accept the fact that it doesn't really have subviews in the normal sense of the word. Two bar button items, right and left, might be all you need here (as I tried to suggest in my earlier comment).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the answer matt. I will try that.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. It works. However, as you said, navigation bar is not intended to be used this way, and also provides very less control over where to position the labels. Therefore, implemented my own slide animation. Thanks.